# Create singleton services in App Module but initialize components in Feature Modules

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, scope

As I knew, a services is declared in a Module will be available in its children, and the service should be singleton (in my opinion if that service do not manage any states of particular module so it should be singleton).

To do so (singleton service) we often export static **forRoot** function in **Feature Module** to initialize app-wide service and that module will be imported in App Module.

Detailed question I would like to ask that a **Feature Module** has services which declared as singleton. But its component in array "declarations" just imports in others **Feature Module** which want to use. For example:

I have used library **angular-tree-component** (https://angular2-tree.readme.io/) which has **TreeModule** that expose static forRoot as the following:

```
var TreeModule = /** @class */ (function () {
    function TreeModule() {
    }
    TreeModule.forRoot = function () {
        return {
            ngModule: TreeModule,
            providers: [TreeDraggedElement]
        };
    };
    TreeModule.decorators = [
        { type: NgModule, args: [{
                    declarations: [
                        TreeComponent,
                        TreeNodeComponent,
                        ...
                    ],
                    exports: [
                        TreeComponent,
                        TreeNodeComponent,
                        ...
                    ],
                    imports: [
                        CommonModule,
                        MobxAngularModule
                    ],
                    providers: []
                },] },
    ];
    return TreeModule;
}());
```

And in App Module will import **TreeModule.forRoot()** and all components (TreeComponent, TreeNodeComponent, ...) of TreeModule will available for application, but some of Modules don't need these components. So what do I have to now? Services are singleton but components just import for specific Modules.

Any help I will appreciate and thank you in advance.

---

**UPDATE 1**

In App Module imports TreeModule.forRoot() and FeatureModuleA also imports TreeModule, so components of TreeModule will be created two times. I consoled log I and that exactly what I thought.

```
// App Module
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    TreeModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {}
}


// FeatureModuleA    
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FeatureComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
    TreeModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
  ]
})
export class FeatureModuleA {
  constructor() {}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you rendering TreeComponent?

Comment: I render it in FeatureModuleA, FeatureModuleB, but not in FeatureModuleC. So that why I want to import components of TreeModule in FeatureA, FeatureB and TreeModule's services will be app-wide. But as my thought so, If it can't do in that way I will accept and import as usual. (TreeModule.forRoot in AppModule and TreeModule in FeatureModuleA, B)

Comment: But importing the module in both modules does what you want. As mentioned in the answer, to use components, you will have to import the module, and no matter how many times you import a module in multiple feature modules, you will get an app-wide instance of the service. UNLESS you are LAZY LOADING a module.

Comment: - Both FeatureA and FeatureB are Lazy Module. As the way I imported services of TreeModule, so that instance of the services are singleton, but not components right?
- Even components initialize more than once, it is normal right?

Comment: Yes it is normal, components are meant to be re usable views. Whenever you render a component, it's initialized again. They are not meant to retain state of the application. State is managed by the services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the module you are using have a forChild method, that doesn't provide the services but exports all the components, directives etc, you can use that in feature modules, otherwise, you'll have to import it the same way you'll do in the Root module. It does not matter unless you are using Lazy loading, you'll still end up with singleton services.

**Edit**
In your Tree Module source code, if you import TreeModule without forRoot, you get only the declarations, so you can just add "TreeModule" in feature modules, and TreeModule.forRoot() in Root Module as it provides all the services.

**Update 1 Response:**
If you want to render components in multiple module, you'll have to import Components in all those modules, and whenever the component is rendered in view, it will be initialized, and hence you see 2 logs.

You can read more here : [Importing HttpClientModule in feature modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57187673/importing-httpclientmodule-in-feature-modules/57188266#57188266)

Comment: To conclude that, if I just want to use components (of library module) in some of FeatureModules, then I have to import these components one by one, not library module. And services of the library to be singleton, that should be called LibModule.forRoot in importing array of App Module.

Comment: You cannot import components, you will have to import the library module, otherwise you'll get error"Component A is a part of declarations of 2 modules". Now each Library module have different definition. Some give the options of forRoot and some doesn't. If it does, it's best to add Module.forRoot() in your AppModule, and Module.forChild() in feature modules. Now tree module does not have forChild(), but importing TreeModule without forRoot does the same thing, ie it does not provide Services. So in your case, import TreeModule in feature modules and TreeModule.forRoot in App module.